# Eclipse tracing.What is best practice?How to get instance of DebugTrace?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on RCP aplicattion, that works on Eclipse 4 platform(Luna). I neeed to find out how to get instance that implement tracing inside my Application. I found out the following ways
 -

- Using ILog interface, that can be get via Platform.getLog call. ILog has good point. It prints to .log file that located in .metadata, but 
  it get IStatus object as parameter. So for logging each line to log I have to created new instance of Status object. And it cannot put automatically information about caller like class name etc.(like Log4j, LogBack)
- I found interface DebugTrace that provide good functionality for traicing. It can be obtained via DebugOptions inerface(DebugOptions.newDebugTrace()). To my regret I could not find appropriated way for getting instance of DebugOptions

Answer (score 1):

To use DebugTrace, add this to the plugin Activator:

```
private DebugTrace tracer = null;

public static DebugTrace getTrace()
{
    return plugin.tracer;
}

public void start(final BundleContext context) throws Exception
{
...

final Hashtable<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<String, String>(4);
properties.put(DebugOptions.LISTENER_SYMBOLICNAME, "org.eclipse.ui.trace"); //$NON-NLS-1$
context.registerService(
    DebugOptionsListener.class.getName(),
    new DebugOptionsListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void optionsChanged(DebugOptions options)
        {
            tracer = options.newDebugTrace(context.getBundle().getSymbolicName());
        }
    }, properties);
```

You will need to add a `.options` file to the plugin project which will contain your logging options:

```
# Editor-related tracing
com.acme.atf.app/trace/editor=false

#Start-up tracing
com.acme.atf.app/trace/startup=true

org.eclipse.core.jobs/jobs=true
org.eclipse.core.jobs/jobs/beginend=true
org.eclipse.core.jobs/jobs/errorondeadlock=true
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Is the file .options mandatory? Can I switch -debug options only while start application?.

Comment: One more questions file .options should be created for each plugin in my application, or it should be one file foe whole application

Comment: You will need to do this for each plugin. It is also possible to change the options at runtime. I think that there is a standard preference page which you can include and enable and modify tracing options. (I'll update my answer when I find the info)